# Updating values within an object's array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm pretty dang new to Javascript and doing some practice on the basics using D&D concepts since I can conceptualize them pretty easily. In this I was playing around with objects, arrays and methods.
Where I'm stuck is figuring how to save the "Gold" I add to playerOne's "coin" and then have it reflect when I run the "getTotalGold" function below. I imagine I might be missing something rather basic or it could just be something I haven't learned yet since I'm still new. Any help is appreciated!

```
const playerOne = {
  name: 'Zolda',
  class: 'Wizard',
  maxHp: 90,
  currentHp: 85,
  armorClass: 16,
  atkBonus: 7,
  coin: [
    {
      type: 'Gold',
      amount: 895,
    },
    {
      type: 'Platinum',
      amount: 132,
    },
    {
      type: 'Silver',
      amount: 6457,
    },
    {
      type: 'Copper',
      amount: 35456,
    },
  ],
  items: [],
  addItem(description, amount) {
    this.items.push({
      description,
      amount,
    });
  },
};

//Adding gold to the object array above
function addGold(newGold) {
  let currentGold = playerOne.coin[0].amount;
  currentGold += newGold;
  return currentGold;
}

//converting the other coin values and adding them together in "Gold" for a //estimate of the total value
function getTotalGold() {
  const baseGold = playerOne.coin[0].amount;
  const platToGold = playerOne.coin[1].amount * 10;
  const silverToGold = Math.floor(playerOne.coin[2].amount / 10);
  const copperToGold = Math.floor(playerOne.coin[3].amount / 100);

  const totalGold = (
    baseGold +
    platToGold +
    silverToGold +
    copperToGold
  ).toFixed(0);
  return `${playerOne.name} has about ${totalGold} gold pieces in total.`;
}

console.log(addGold(500));
console.log(getTotalGold());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the added amount of gold *back to the object* - reassigning the variable name alone to a new number won't change the property in the object:

```
function addGold(newGold) {
  let currentGold = playerOne.coin[0].amount;
  currentGold += newGold;
  return currentGold;
}
```

should be

```
function addGold(newGold) {
  playerOne.coin[0].amount += newGold;
  return playerOne.coin[0].amount;
}
```

```js
const playerOne = {
  name: 'Zolda',
  class: 'Wizard',
  maxHp: 90,
  currentHp: 85,
  armorClass: 16,
  atkBonus: 7,
  coin: [
    {
      type: 'Gold',
      amount: 895,
    },
    {
      type: 'Platinum',
      amount: 132,
    },
    {
      type: 'Silver',
      amount: 6457,
    },
    {
      type: 'Copper',
      amount: 35456,
    },
  ],
  items: [],
  addItem(description, amount) {
    this.items.push({
      description,
      amount,
    });
  },
};

//Adding gold to the object array above
function addGold(newGold) {
  playerOne.coin[0].amount += newGold;
  return playerOne.coin[0].amount;
}

//converting the other coin values and adding them together in "Gold" for a //estimate of the total value
function getTotalGold() {
  const baseGold = playerOne.coin[0].amount;
  const platToGold = playerOne.coin[1].amount * 10;
  const silverToGold = Math.floor(playerOne.coin[2].amount / 10);
  const copperToGold = Math.floor(playerOne.coin[3].amount / 100);

  const totalGold = (
    baseGold +
    platToGold +
    silverToGold +
    copperToGold
  ).toFixed(0);
  return `${playerOne.name} has about ${totalGold} gold pieces in total.`;
}

console.log(addGold(500));
console.log(getTotalGold());
```